# Trust this computer - what is shared?

Tags: iphone, security, ios

Apologies if this has been asked before, but when you trust a computer, what data is shared?

I'm on iOS 8 and have been plugging my personal phone into my work PC for charging. I click "trust" because I thought if I clicked "don't trust" it wouldn't charge.

It says data, contacts, and other things of that nature are shared when clicking "Trust." Apple seems pretty vague with "other things." My question is, is it possible that my text messages are synced to my work computer when I hit "trust"? If so, can my employer read them? I tried looking online but couldn't find anything about text data being stored on a PC computer after clicking "Trust."

I only ask because I've been considering leaving my company and texted a friend about it. Thanks!

Comment: Clicking "Don't Trust" will not prevent your phone from charging.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you explicitly backed up your iPhone to your work PC using iTunes (or ran some other type of program like Macroplant's iExplorer), you're probably fine. Tapping the "Trust" button does allow a computer to access an iPhone's information, but doesn't *initiate* any particular kind of access.

For more information, see ['Trust This Computer' alert on iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5868).

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. When I click on my little iPhone button on my work PC, I just see my pictures in the folder but nothing else. Is there a way I can check on the PC to see if my texts synced? From my knowledge, I can't even see my synced texts on my Mac when I'm connected.

Comment: If there were a malicious program on your work computer saving your text messages, it could save them anywhere — or have already transmitted them somewhere else. Again, though, this seems unlikely.

I'd only worry if you inadvertently did an iTunes backup. You can check to see if there are any iTunes backups in your user folder. See [Create and delete iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch backups in iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4946) for information on what iTunes backs up and how to remove unwanted backups.

Answer (score 0):

No your test messages can't be synced on your computer, though your contacts and data can, go in iTunes and you can manually manage the data which you want or do not want to be synced by iTunes,

for eg: when you connect your device to iTunes, Select your device and click on the respective tabs which appear on the iTunes menu , if you choose Music, then it will show you the below Screen

[image]

you can uncheck the sync option if you don't want to be syncing your data to your PC